# MVC Strongly typed IQueryable<IGrouping<TKey, TElement>> model

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, linq, razor

I'm trying to create a strongly typed model for one of my Views in MVC. The model is the result of a LINQ GroupBy query so it is the type shown below (grouping employees by first letter of surname).

```
@model IQueryable<IGrouping<string, Employee>>
```

I'm unsure why but it doesn't let me have a model of this type. The error message I get is:
An opening "<" is missing the corresponding closing ">". Which is incorrect.

I know I can create a view specific model and populate that instead but I'd like to know why this model doesn't seem to work?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't know why you'd be getting this error, since you appear to be using correct Razor code. It's possible that there's actually a bug elsewhere in the page that is being made manifest through this incorrect error message.

A workaround, which may help you determine the real source of the bug, would be to create your own strongly-typed model class, which could have this data as its property:

```
public class EmployeeListViewModel
{
    public IQueryable<IGrouping<string, Employee>> EmployeesByCompanyTitle {get;set;}
}
```

(There are those who would argue that this is a better approach anyway, since you can now add information to your view model more easily.)

Comment: There are no errors in the rest of the page and the itellisense of the page only stops working when this top @model line is used (as if that line is syntactically incorrect) so it's pretty much narrowed down to that. Could it potentially be the fact that Iqueryable takes a generic and igrouping also takes a generic so for what ever reason this cannot be used as a strongly type model? It looks like I may have to create a specific view model.

Comment: @robasaurus: There should be no problem with nested generics. I tried it on my machine and it works just fine. Is it possible that Visual Studio isn't recognizing this as a Razor view? Try creating a specific view model and see if that works. The error you're getting, and the fact that it sounds like the rest of your page doesn't currently rely on the model, makes me think maybe VS is just treating your content like a regular html or aspx/ascx page, rather than a Razor (.cshtml) page.

Comment: I have created a view model and that works fine. So it's definately treating the page as a razor view because I have used razor syntax to loop through the custom view model. Which is great but I'm still puzzled as to why it didnt work.

Answer (score 3):

By default, a very limited set of namespaces are available for direct use in razor views. Try to expand it to fully qualified names and see if the problem persists:

```
@model System.Linq.IQueryable<System.Linq.IGrouping<string, Name.Space.Employee>>
```

Comment: Gave that a go but it doesn't seem to be the problem. When the view has the top line as that statement it breaks the itellisense for the rest of the page as if it is syntactially incorrect, although I'm 100% sure it's correct because I copied it from my controller code which returns the model.